# Remove line breaks and paragraph breaks from textarea

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to 'flatten' (removing line breaks and paragraph breaks) from any given input from a textarea.

**Suppose the input is:**

```
select * where { 
    ?s ?p ?o .
} limit 100
```

**The expected outcome is:**

```
select * where { ?s ?p ?o . } limit 100
```

So far I have managed to remove the line breaks using the following piece of code:

```
val.replace(/$(\r|\n)(?=.)/gm, ' ');
```

Which is currently giving me:

```
select * where {    ?s ?p ?o . } limit 100
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\s*[\r\n]+\s*` replace with space.

Comment: `.replace(/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/g, ' ')` or more efficient `.replace(/[^\S\r\n]*[\r\n]+\s*/g, ' ')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Excellent, thanks!

Comment: I may not be understanding, but why is `.replace(/\s+/gm, ' ')` not sufficient?

Comment: @Unimportant If there is a string of more than one space inside a line it will also reduce that part of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Add the space character `\s` to your match criteria, and also add a `*` to signify that there can be more than one concurrent match. From here you'll simply want to replace such characters with an empty string instead of a space.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
const val = `select * where { 
    ?s ?p ?o .
} limit 100 `;

console.log(val.replace(/$(\r|\n|\s)*(?=.)/gm, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
val = val.replace(/[^\S\r\n]*[\r\n]+\s*/g, ' ')
```

This will "shrink" linebreaks (including any consecutive blank lines) with adjacent whitespaces into a single space char.

Here,

- `[^\S\r\n]*` - matches 0+ horizontal spaces
- `[\r\n]+` - 1+ CR or LF chars
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespce chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jaNBsh/1).

Answer (score 1):

About CRLF:
- As  @Unimportant suggests, replace `\s+` with space.
Reason is that formatting the result won't work anyway it's done.
Better to be consistent with even looking separation.

About Paragraph breaks and Breaks:
- Would be replace `</?p\s*>|<br\s*/>` with nothing.

So, 2 separate regex run independent of each other would do the job.